# Android Clients communicating over GAE

Tags: android, google-app-engine

What is the best way for 2 android clients to communicate over gae? Sometimes my server app(on GAE) has to send push notifications to clients. I have tried Channel API on javascript clients. C2DM services seems not be a good solution at this moment.
Does any have some suggestions for me?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is currently not possible with GAE. The Channel API is only for used in Browsers.

But you could use a 3rd party pushing service for that (have a look at http://pusher.com/ or http://www.pubnub.com/) and combine this services with the GAE services (like the Datastore or Task Queue).